# Get MonoBehaviour components from Prefab

Tags: unity, javascript

I need to assign the script values for the following Prefab in Unity 3.5

```
The structure is the following
```

Kinect_Prefab

```
 -MonoBehaviour

    ·Script: Missing Mono Script

 -MonoBehaviour

    ·Script: Missing Mono Script

 -MonoBehaviour

    ·Script: Missing Mono Script 

 -MonoBehaviour

    ·Script: Missing Mono Script
```

All the components have the same name.

I have tried to obtain all of them in an array, but the `GetComponents` method does not seem to work properly.

```
var mono : MonoBehaviour[]; 
mono = Kinect_Prefab.GetComponents(MonoBehaviour);
```

The thing is the resulting array is empty.

Any idea what might be wrong?

EDIT: When I do GetComponents(MonoBehaviour) I get the following error

`InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.`

I have tried receiving the components in var mono : Component [] but I still don't receive anything

Comment: Normally people would get the components like this "Kinect_Prefab.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>();" but unless you are receiving a compilation error I doubt that is your problem. Could the scripts you are looking for be attached to children of the prefab?

Comment: If you try it with `GetComponent` do you get a single component back?  Why are you using the base class MonoBehaviour instead of something you implemented?

Comment: @Tetrad Using only GetComponent I get a null object

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I need to attach the scripts to those Monobehaviour components

Comment: When you say "attach the scripts" do you mean you need to assign a variable to a script you made or do you mean you need to attach the script you made to the prefab itself?  For the former you need to get the specific derived type so you can access the variable. For the latter you want to `AddComponent` instead and what you're asking doesn't make any sense. What does the prefab look like in the inspector?

Comment: @Tetrad I need to attach the script I made for the prefab to the existing Monobehaviour component, not to a new one.

The idea is to assign my scripts to the monobehaviour components (To the missing mono script parts).

Comment: @Tetrad I want to define the existing components not to add new ones. I have edited the description to see if its clearer.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want to do at runtime. I'm assuming you want to set the script on the mono behavior to preserve serialized data.  If not you could just add the component and call it a day.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Generally speaking, a script is a C# class that extends MonoBehaviour. Now not all scripts extend Monobehaviour, that is just a requirement if you want to attach the script to a GameObject. Anyway so there are two things I think you are asking, the first was how to get components and I mentioned "GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>()" already, the second is how to add a script at runtime which is something like "ScriptClassName script = gameObjectVariable.AddComponent(typeof (ScriptClassName)) as ScriptClassName;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be completely off... but it seems like you have no scripts attached to the `Kinect_Prefab` - that's why it says `Script: Missing Mono Script`. This means that scripts were previously attached but they were deleted (did you rename them?)

What you have to do, is remove all the existing script components that say that a script is missing, and attach new ones (by dragging scripts on to the prefab object):

[image: Missing script]

[image: Removing component]

Once you've done that, your other scripts will be able to access the `MonoBehavior` objects of the attached scripts.

Comment: In effect you cannot change Monobehaviour scripts in runtime.  I just edited the prefab to include the scripts and solved the problem.